# "Skew" Eigenpairs

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is a familiar definition that a pair $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair of a complex matrix $A$ if $v \neq 0$ and $Av = \lambda v$.

During research, I encountered a similar definition. I call a pair $(\lambda, v)$ a **skew eigenpair** if $v \neq 0$ and
$$Av = \lambda \bar{v}$$
where $\bar{v}$ denote complex conjugation.

It is not clear to me which properties of eigenpairs hold for these objects. For example, a general $n \times n$ complex matrix can have more than $n$ "skew eigenvalues", as illustrated by the $1 \times 1$ identity matrix. In this case, any complex number on the unit circle can be a skew eigenvalue.

Does anyone know what these things are called in literature? Where can I find more reference on them?

I am especially interested in the case when $A$ is unitary. In this case, it is clear that all skew eigenvalues of $A$ lies on the unit circle. However, fundamental properties, like the number of skew eigenvalues, continues to elude me. I'll ask a concrete question to motivate the discussion

**Question**: How many $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent skew eigenpairs can an $n \times n$ unitary matrix $A$ have?

**Edit**: I just realized that if $(\lambda, v)$ is a skew eigenpair, then $\lambda z$ must be a skew eigenvalue for $z$ with absolute value $1$, with skew eigenvector $\sqrt{\lambda} v$. Thus, I guess the following question makes more sense.

**Question**: Does every  $n \times n$ unitary matrix $A$ admit a basis of skew eigenpairs?

**Edit**: user1551's comment below has pointed out a necessary condition for this to occur. The special case I am studying happen to satisfy this condition, so let's add this constraint.

**Question**: Does every  $n \times n$ symmetric unitary matrix $A$ admit a basis of skew eigenpairs?

Comment: It's certainly a more complicated beast. If $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigen pair, and $\alpha\neq0,$ then $(\lambda,\alpha v)$ is also an eigen-pair, but this would not be true for your skew version, unless $\alpha$ is real.

Comment: Yes I agree. I wouldn't be asking if I could make sense of these objects immediately :-).

Comment: Note e.g. that in the $n = 1$ case (i.e. on $\mathbb{C}$) the identity operator has at least two skew eigenvalues, because $1 \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot \overline{1}$ and $1 \cdot i = (-1) \cdot \overline{i}$

Comment: I see! I'll rephrase the question with this new insight.

Comment: The other thing about this definition is that if you change the basis of your vectors, a skew eigen-pair might no longer be a skew eigen-pair - the complex conjugate of a vector is highly dependent on the basis it is represented in, so it isn't a pure property of the linear operation, $A.$

Comment: Yes I agree. I guess the definition is more ``well defined" if you view complex conjugation as a real linear operation $J$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold.

Comment: $Av=\lambda\overline{v}$ implies that $\overline{Av}=\overline{\lambda}v$ and in turn $\overline{A}Av=|\lambda|^2v$. If $A$ has a skew eigenbasis, $\overline{A}A$ necessarily has a real spectrum. Yet this necessary condition is not always satisfied. E.g. when $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\ i&-i}$, the eigenvalues of $\overline{A}A=\frac12\pmatrix{1+i&1-i\\ -1-i&1-i}$ are $\frac12(1\pm\sqrt{3}i)$.

Comment: Ah I see... It looks like I should add one more condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer to the last question is yes.

**Proposition**: Every $n \times n$ unitary, symmetric matrix $A$ admits a basis of skew eigenpairs.

**Proof**: It is familiar that every unitary matrix admits a basis of eigenvectors. What is special about a symmetric unitary matrix is that it admits a basis of **real** eigenvectors. Every real eigenvector is automatically a skew eigenvector, so we are done.

To see how to find a basis of real eigenvectors, suppose $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$. Then
$$Av = \lambda v.$$
Now we use the fact that $\bar{A} A = I$. Multiply both sides by $\bar{A}$ gives
$$v = \lambda \bar{A} v.$$
As $\lambda$ must be a unit vector, we get
$$\bar{\lambda} v = \bar{A} v.$$
And conjugating gives
$$A \bar{v} = \lambda \bar{v}.$$
So $(\lambda, \bar{v})$ is also an eigenpair! Taking linear combination, we conclude that $\Re v$ and $\Im v$ are both eigenvector. Thus, from a basis of complex eigenvectors $v_1, \cdots, v_n$, we can get a collection of real eigenvectors $\{\Re v_i, \Im v_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ that span $\mathbb{C}^n$, as desired. \qed